# constructor initialize variable to null cause NPE for jdbc

Tags: java

i have this class where i use to retrieve data from database.create a constructor, then if initialize all variable to null --> NPE. so i commented them, works like magic. my question, why or how this happen? does everytime obj class use a method it would go back to constructor so set all variable to null? interested to know.sorry for my lack of knowledge if this so simple. Thanks.

```
public class OptionList {

private Connection conn;
private List<String> type_list = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> partid_list = new ArrayList<>();

public OptionList() {
    //conn = null;
    //type_list = null;
    //partid_list = null;
}

public void listin_db() throws Exception, SQLException {
    JDBC ora = new JDBC();

    //1. open/get connection
    ora.openConnection();

    conn = ora.getConn();

    //2. Execute query
    String stmnt = " select distinct PARTID, NAME "
            + " from INVENTORY tblA "
            + " inner join( "
            + " select distinct part_no "
            + " from Status )tblB on tblA.Partid = tblB.part_no ";
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(stmnt);

    while (rs.next()) {
        type_list.add((String) rs.getString("NAME"));
        partid_list.add((String) rs.getString("PARTID"));
    }

    conn.close();
    statement.close();
    ora.closeConnection();

}

public List<String> getpartid_List() {
    return partid_list;
}

public List<String> getType_List() {
    return type_list;
}

public String test() {
    return "HelooWourldd!";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NPE will be on this line

```
type_list.add((String) rs.getString("NAME"));
```

because you have set type_list to null in constructor.

When you initialise instance variables like this

```
private List<String> type_list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

it is equivalent to this code in constructor

```
public OptionList() { 
    this.type_list = new ArrayList<String>();
 }
```

Which means type_list is not null when you iterate over the result set.

Comment: yes..the constructor should be like that, seems like i had pre-initialise as instance variable and de-initialise the variable in the constructor.this is more clear of what im doing..thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you initialize the array members when you declare them :

```
private List<String> type_list = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> partid_list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Afterwards, the constructor sets them to null (in the commented out code) :

```
public OptionList() {
    //conn = null;
    //type_list = null;
    //partid_list = null;
}
```

Then, when you try to add Strings to them, in `listin_db()`, you get the `NullPointerException`.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    type_list.add((String) rs.getString("NAME"));
    partid_list.add((String) rs.getString("PARTID"));
}
```

You should either initialize them when declaring them (as you do now), or in the constructor, but you can't initialize them to null, and then try to access them.